Fixed points above the decompactification scale vs black hole entropy
Asymptotic safety is the hypothesis that there is a UV fixed point in quantum gravity. One critique is that this is incompatible with the holographic understanding of how black hole entropy scales (i.e. with the horizon rather than with the volume), since it would imply that $n$-dimensional quantum gravity scales in the UV like an $n$-dimensional conformal field theory, rather than an $(n-1)$-dimensional theory.
Recently Abel, Dienes, and Nutricati have claimed the discovery of effective fixed-point behavior in string theory, above the decompactification scale. I am wondering if this is also in tension with the expected scaling of black hole entropy; or if not, why not.
